# Serialize JSON in VB.NET

Tags: json, vb.net

I'd like to send a JSON message via a socket.

How do I serialize my message? Is there an equivalent to JSON.stringify in VB.NET?

Here is my function to establish a connection with the server via socket.

```
Public Sub SendCommand(Command As String)
    Dim SocketClient As New Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)
    Dim EP As New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 5000)
    Try
        SocketClient.Connect(EP)
        Dim Mess As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Command)
        SocketClient.Send(Mess)
        SocketClient.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' Error
    End Try
End Sub
```

Keys of my JSON message contain hyphens.

```
SendCommand("{""my-key1"":""myvalue1"",""my-key2"":""myvalue2"",""my-key3"":""myvalue3""}")
```

I don't have the opportunity to integrate new libraries, as Json.NET for example.

Thanks for help, I'm a beginner.

Comment: Can you referece [JavaScriptSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer)? Where does this schema come from? See if you can remove the hyphens.

Comment: You can for example create a dictionary, .add(key1,value1)...then serialize and send.

Comment: @Jimi I added this: `Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization` and `Dim js As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer`
But I get an error: `Namespace or type specified in the Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member...`
I don't know how to refer to System.Web.Extensions.dll, I only use a basic text editor. The schema comes from software that can be controlled via sockets, so I can't unfortunately remove the hyphens.

Comment: @CruleD Like this?
`Dim dictionary As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
dictionary.Add("my-key1", "myvalue1")
Dim Mess As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dictionary)
SocketClient.Send(Mess)`

Comment: `Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization` is correct. You have to add `System.Web` as a Reference to your Project (`Project -> References -> Add Reference...`). Then you can write:  `Dim json = New JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(myClassObject)`. Where `myClassObject` is the class that generates the string you're showing. But you probably have a Dictionary as data source, so: `Dim json = New JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(myDictionary)`

Comment: Why can't you add other libraries? Most modern .NET programs are essentially collections of libraries delivered as nuget packages...half the framework itself is added that way. JSON.NET is just another nuget package. If you use something like the Web API framework you find it's bundled by default when you create the project. I can't see a sensible reason why you couldn't use it.. what's the restriction, really?

Comment: If you don't want to use JSON.Net then you have to use JavaScriptSerializer (.SerializeObject) to make that dictionary into JSON. Then, you send it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Class with the keys of your JSON message as variables. If you have a nested JSON, then create the key where another JSON is present as an 'Object' type variable in the class.

Create object of the above created Class and serialize it using **NewtonSoft.Json**.

Refer the link: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm

**NewtonSoft.Json** is an open source library in .Net (VB & C#) for JSON activities.